# Using VirtualBox SDK without VirtualBox

Tags: c, winapi, com, virtualbox

I'm trying start a virtual box machine using the virtual box SDK. I've managed to successfully do this using the mscom sample that is provided in the SDK directory, but **only with VirtualBox installed**.
On a machine without VirtualBox installed this no longer works.

Is there some way I can accomplish this without having to install the entire VirtualBox software? Maybe just register a dll or something?

This is the code I'm using (it's almost the same as the one provided by the SDK):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HRESULT rc;
    IVirtualBox *virtualBox;

    /* Initialize the COM subsystem. */
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    /* Instantiate the VirtualBox root object. */
 /*######## the following line fails with error 0x80040154 (Class not registered) ######## */
    rc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VirtualBox,       /* the VirtualBox base object */
                            NULL,                   /* no aggregation */
                            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,    /* the object lives in a server process on this machine */
                            IID_IVirtualBox,        /* IID of the interface */
                            (void**)&virtualBox);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {
        printf("Error creating VirtualBox instance! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }

    listVMs(virtualBox);

    /* Enable the following line to get a VM started. */
    //testStartVM(virtualBox);

    /* Release the VirtualBox object. */
    virtualBox->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Erm, you're trying to start VirtualBox on a machine that doesn't have VirtualBox? Or do you really want to get a remote machine's IVirtualBox instance and start VirtualBox remotely?

Comment: Or do you think the COM module is all you need to be able to run a full VirtualBox VM? That's not how COM works, and that's not how VirtualBox works. You need the complete package to use the VM, and you can't just create a rogue background VM and run it; every VM has to be accessible to the user.

Comment: That's kind of what I want and I'm asking if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point in trying to access VirtualBox VMs when VirtualBox itself is not installed? `CoCreateInstance()` will simply fail with a `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` error ("*A specified class is not registered in the registration database*") if the COM object is not found.  That is exactly the error you are getting.  There is nothing you can do about that if VirtualBox is not installed.  And you should not try to install the VirtualBox COM object by itself just to satisfy your code.  Just handle the error and move on, there are no VirtualBox VMs available on that machine at that time.

BTW, if `CoCreateInstance()` fails, you still need to call `CoUninitialize()` if `CoInitialize()` succeeded (which you are not checking for).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HRESULT rc;
    IVirtualBox *virtualBox;

    /* Initialize the COM subsystem. */
    rc = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(rc))
    {    
        printf("Error initializing COM! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Instantiate the VirtualBox root object. */
    rc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VirtualBox,       /* the VirtualBox base object */
                            NULL,                   /* no aggregation */
                            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,    /* the object lives in a server process on this machine */
                            IID_IVirtualBox,        /* IID of the interface */
                            (void**)&virtualBox);

    if (FAILED(rc))
    {
        if (rc == REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)
            printf("VirtualBox not detected! Please install it.\n");
        else
            printf("Error creating VirtualBox instance! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);

        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    listVMs(virtualBox);

    /* Enable the following line to get a VM started. */
    //testStartVM(virtualBox);

    /* Release the VirtualBox object. */
    virtualBox->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably just a drive-by vote for answering an outrageously stupid question.

Comment: VirtualBox installs a lot of stuff. I know it doesn't make sense to try and access a VM without having VirtualBox installed at all. What I'm asking is if there's a minimal subset of all the things VirtualBox installs that I can use achieve what I want. That's my question. If it's not possible, just say so :) I'm aware that what I want is unlikely, but I just needed some confirmation.

Comment: @conectionist: The *"minimal subset"* you are looking for is the COM infrastructure built into the OS. If an attempt to instantiate a COM object fails because that class hasn't been registered, it'll kindly inform you. It doesn't care whether this is for a Virtual Box or some other interface.

Comment: @conectionist what EXACTLY do you want to achieve? Why do you want to install extra files on a machine (even if it is possible) just to prevent `CoCreateInstance()` from failing, just to have the next step (querying the COM object) not do anything meaningful anyway? What are you REALLY trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to run a virtual machine (from a ovf file), in the background (GUI-less) without having to install the whole VirtualBox package.

Comment: @conectionist sorry, but you cannot *RUN* a VM (GUI-less or otherwise) without a full VM installation to provide the underlying functionally, whether that be VirtualBox, VMWare, etc. You cannot pick-and-choose pieces to install, it is all or nothing. VMs are complicated, they require a LOT of things to be in place since entire systems are being emulated in a virtual environment. Your goal is unrealistic, just install VirtualBox (or VMWare, or whatever) and be done with it.